# GestureDetector and GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: java, android, api, gestures, gesturedetector

What is the difference between GestureDetector Class and the GestureDetectorCompat class? Both to do the same thing(deal with gestures) but which one should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GestureDetectorCompat enables your to use all of the GestureDetector capability on old android version. That's all.

So you probably want to use the compat version which has identical APIs.